# Extract entries > 0 and their locations from matrix A and insert into matrix B?

Tags: r, matrix, logical-operators, indices

I have a question regarding matrices in R :

-To extract elements of a matrix that are > 0 and to put it in the list for a  matrix below:

matA : `structure(c(10, 0, 0, 5, 0, 5), .Dim = 2:3)`

I can simply say: `matA[matA>0]`

- Is it possible to extract the location of the above numbers? So that (if required in a scenario) I can place them back into a new matrix of the same dimensions at the same location?
  for example: If I have 
  `matB <- matrix(, nrow=2,ncol=3)`. 
  Can I place the list elements back to the same location in `matB` as in `matA`?

Silly question but I need to perform such operation in a scenario!

Comment: Thanks! @ZheyuanLi

Comment: @ZheyuanLi : It seems to be a duplicate. I agree. Just read the other thread.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi : I did! cheers